# Grouping issue with addJSONData

Tags: jqgrid

I have some issue with jqGrid paging. I want create own group and add row data to it. While I add data to grid on the first page its Ok, but if add new group on the next page, I can see exception in Firebug and empty page. I use addJSONData method. The problem is that addJSONData iterate through all groups in Grid and look for their length:

```
str += "<tr id=\""+hid+"\" role=\"row\" class= \"ui-widget-content jqgroup ui-row-"+$t.p.direction+"\"><td colspan=\""+colspans+"\">"+icon+$.jgrid.format(grp.groupText[0], gv, grdata[n].length)+"</td></tr>";
```

But if I have one group on previous page and only sent data of second group with ajax and call addJSONData it throws exception: length of undefined. How can I solve it?

**UPDATE:** Here is my code:

```
function addToGrid(group, ids){
  var rowNum = jQuery(myGrid).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'rowNum');
  data = jQuery.ajax({
    url: myUrl,
    data: {'group': group, 'rowNum': rowNum, 'ids': ids},
    dataType: 'json',
    complete: function(jsondata,stat){
       if(stat=="success") {
          var targetGrid = jQuery(myGrid);
          var myjsongrid = eval('('+jsondata.responseText+')'); 
          var rows = myjsongrid.rows;
          if(rows.length != 0){
               targetGrid[0].addJSONData(myjsongrid);
          }           
       }
    }
 });
```

}

And table:

```
$(myGrid).jqGrid({
    url: myUrlTable,
    datatype: 'json',
    postData: {},
    mtype: 'GET',
    jsonReader: { repeatitems : false},
    colNames: ['Id', 'Group', 'Bytes'],
    colModel: [{name:'id', index: 'id', hidden: true},
               {name:'group', index: 'group', width: 100},
               {name:'bytes', index: 'bytes', width: 60, classes:'gc column-bytes', sortable: false, sorttype:'int', formatter:'integer'}
               ],
    grouping: true,
    groupingView: { 
        groupField : ['group'],
        groupText : ['Group: ({1} items)'],
        groupOrder: 'asc',
        groupDataSorted : true
    },
    sortable: true,
    toppager: true,
    hoverrows: true,
    altrows: false,
});
```

Test data from server:

```
{"total":1,"page":1,"records":1,"rows":[{"group":"abc", "bytes":229447,"id":"7124"}]}
```

Another records are similar. I added 20 records and then I added next 5 on another page with group bbb.
Method addToGrid is called from another grid and with ids and entered group name to input dialog. Then I pass it to server and server returns valid data to fulefill grid. Server returns only data for the last page in my case 5 rows.

Server response:

```
 {"total":2,"page":2,"records":5,"rows":[{"group":"bbb", "bytes":229447,"id":"7155"},
                                         {"group":"bbb", "bytes":229447,"id":"7156"},
                                         {"group":"bbb", "bytes":229447,"id":"7157"},
                                         {"group":"bbb", "bytes":229447,"id":"7158"},
                                         {"group":"bbb", "bytes":229447,"id":"7159"}
                                        ]
 }
```

Comment: I don't understand **why** you need to use `addJSONData` method to add data in the grid. Do you have local data or do you load the data manually from the server per ajax on every paging of jqGrid? If you would include in your question the JavaScript code which you currently use including the test JSON data I could try to show how you could **do the same without `addJSONData`**.

Comment: where is the jqGrid definition? Where are the test JSON data? Who calls the `addToGrid` method? Do the user it manually? Is the call in some `onclick` handler? To be able to help you I need first be able to understand and to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I hope there is enough information. Thre is no problem with server or grid data, it works perfectly until I added **grouping: true** flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As  @unknown user mentioned in this case you should call groupingSetup method before to call addJsonData, but this is not enough in case you have  change the grouping and other parameters dynamically.

You will need to set the changed grouped parameters with setGridParam method before to call groupingSetup.

More you can find in our new [Guriddo jqGrid documentation](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/grouping/)

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

i also got the same problem.following line would fix the code.

```
$("#jqGrid").jqGrid("groupingSetup");
```

add this code before **addJSONData** function.

```
function addToGrid(group, ids){
  var rowNum = jQuery(myGrid).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'rowNum');
  data = jQuery.ajax({
    url: myUrl,
    data: {'group': group, 'rowNum': rowNum, 'ids': ids},
    dataType: 'json',
    complete: function(jsondata,stat){
       if(stat=="success") {
$("#myGrid").jqGrid("groupingSetup");
          var targetGrid = jQuery(myGrid);
          var myjsongrid = eval('('+jsondata.responseText+')'); 
          var rows = myjsongrid.rows;
          if(rows.length != 0){
               targetGrid[0].addJSONData(myjsongrid);
          }           
       }
    }
 });
```